# Runtime UI issue caused by "View as: xxx" in storyboard editor

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

My app has a UI bug caused by some unexpected view width in runtime, e.g. it is 375 when it should be 320. But that might not be relevant to the question I’m trying to ask here. That bug was fixed by only changing from **“View as: iPhone 7”** to **“View as: iPhone 4s”** in my main storyboard (see attached screenshots). BTW there is no warnings and errors in the storyboard.

I’m using Xcode 8.3.2 and always test on iPhone SE simulator and iPhone 5s device.

So my question is: should this change of “View as: xxx” in storyboard editor affect the behavior of an app? If I want that this change will never change the behavior of my app, where in the storyboard should I check? Or what storyboard config I missed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, storyboard configuration shouldn't affect actual app behaviour. Can you please add an image of what issue was caused. Also what do you mean by -*"If I want that this change will never change the behavior of my app, where in the storyboard should I check?"*

Comment: @Priyal with that sentence I mean that my app shouldn't be affected by how I view the storyboard, either View-as-iPhone-7 or View-as-iPhone-4s. I understand that there are tons of modifications in the text content of the .storyboard file by switching View-as. It happens to every app of mine. But only in this app, a tableview's width changed from 375 to 320 between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, when I used View-as-iPhone-7. By selecting View-as-iPhone-4s, the problem was gone.

Comment: It can be a random bug in Xcode. Not sure.

Comment: I got the same issue, did you found a solution ?